# Laravel Localization does not return translated string

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9, laravel-localization

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.
I want my application to use "np" as its default locale. So I change the locale key in config/app.php to 'np.' And when I check for the current location in my controller, it returns 'np', so it's working fine until here. Then I created a "np.json" file directly inside the lang directory, which has the following content:

```
{
    "Candidate": "उम्मेदवार"
}
```

Now when I try to return the translated string using:

```
__('Candidate')
```

It returns "Candidate" instead of "उम्मेदवार", even if the current locale function still returns "np". So I ran the following commands trying to clear the cache.

```
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

But still, the issue persists.

Comment: You need to send first, `app()->setLocale('np');` then try

Comment: Double check to confirm that the file is readable try `dd(File::isReadable(lang_path('np.json')))` in the controller

Comment: @apokryfos ah yes therein lies the issue. File::isReadable(lang_path('np.json')) returned false. It looks like the lang_path() was the lang folder inside resources directory. I don't know if I caused this or if this is the default path. Anyway, putting the np.json file inside the resources/lang directory worked. So thank you for your help.

Comment: The issue is that until Laravel 8 the language path was indeed under resources and in Laravel 9 it moved **but** to not break older applications during migration it does still default to <base>/resources/lang and only if that does not exist does it use <base>/lang. Presumably the app you are working on previously used an older version and was upgraded (as is common). You can move that whole folder to <base>/lang if you want or keep it where it is, as long as you are aware where it is.

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you for the explanation. It looks like one of the package that I used created the resources/lang folder when I published it's resource files.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the `lang/` folder with the translations.

If the `lang/` folder is located in the root of the program, move it to the `resources/` folder.

Otherwise, try moving `lang/` to the root of the project.

This is due to the version of Laravel you are using.

Comment: As simple as that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the translations like `<filename>.translation_string`, and that file has be placed inside a folder with your language code.

In your case, create a folder inside `lang` called `np`, then place a translation file (example: `mystrings.php`) in it, so you have this file in a folder `lang/np/mystrings.php`.

Your trans file looks like

```
<?php
return [
  'Candidate' => 'उम्मेदवार',
];
```

Now, you have to set the lang to your language `np` with `app()->setLocale('np');` or you set it directly in your `.env` and now you can call

```
echo __('mystrings.Candidate');
```

to get your translation.
Hope it helps

Comment: "_and that file has be placed inside a folder with your language code_" Laravel 9 also supports the JSON approach OP took.

Comment: @brombeer Sure, my indention is to place a "general valid" example ;)